# When closing books for the year, do you group by posted date or entered date?

Tags: accounting

Say you close your books yearly on December 31, 11:59pm. There's a transaction on a credit card that you made on Dec 29th, but it doesn't post with the bank until Jan 2nd. Would you include that transaction in the last year's books or the new year's books? For my modest personal accounting I can't really think of any reason why it matters one way or another, but was just wondering if there's any professional standard for this, or some consideration I'm not thinking of.

N.B. In my accounting system I record both dates.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dupe, I'm not finding an answer by searching.

Comment: Although the linked answer refers to 'accrual accounting', for personal purposes "cash-based" accounting likely meets all your needs with fewer headaches. You can google 'cash accounting vs accrual accounting' to learn more.

Comment: That helps, thanks